# If cell in column has data then copy and paste to a different cell in same row

Tags: excel, copy, paste, vba

I have data in column in BR and I'm trying to get my macro to work so that if the cell is not blank then it copies and pastes the data to column AO on the same row.

I have this so far but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To Range("BR" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, "BR").Value >= "1" Then .Cut Destination:=Cells(i, "AO")
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean not blank or greater than 1?

```
For i = 1 To Range("BR" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, 70).Value <> "" Then Cells(i, 41).Value = Cells(i, 70).Value
Next i
```

Comment: No worries, feel free to accept if an answer has helped.